# error jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I just download jquery mobile 1.2.0

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

But I have this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

I have the same error when I run the project on an android device with phonegap

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PhoneGap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello PhoneGap !!!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascript/cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascript/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascript/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page: http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/about/getting-started.html

"jQuery Mobile 1.3 RC1 (1.3.0-rc.1) works with versions of jQuery core from 1.7.0 to 1.9.0."

So my guess is that you need to back down your jQuery core to 1.9.0, at least, if you upgrade to jQuery Mobile 1.3 RC1.

Looks like 1.8.2 for jQuery 1.2.0: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/

Comment: Thanks, it works with 1.3 bur is there a lots of risks working with this version ?

Comment: My limited experience is that jQuery mobile is REALLY sensitive to the core version. That's why had this answer so fast. I've run into it myself.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the

jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

to your list of referenced scripts